# Gracefully migrate primary domain controller and DNS/DHCP role

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, active-directory, dhcp

I currently have 2 domain controllers (`pdc` and `sdc`) on Windows Server 2008.  Domain and Forest levels are both 2008.  Both are global catalog servers and are DNS servers.  The server `pdc` is also my DHCP server and has all my FSMO roles.

Last night I promoted a new domain controller (also Server 2008).  It is also a global catalog server.  I want this new domain controller (called `DC-Primary`) to be my primary domain controller, have the DNS and DHCP role, with the current DNS/DHCP settings and database moved to this new server.  Once it has the DNS role and DNS is moved from `pdc` I want to change the IP address of `DC-Primary` to match that of `pdc`.  This is so my clients that have their DNS pointing to `pdc` won't need the DNS ip address updated.

It's been about 10 years since I've had to do this, so I just want to make sure I do this properly.  I know I need to transfer roles but I want to make sure I do everything in the proper order.  End goal is to remove `pdc` as a domain controller all together and shut it down.  This of course after moving FSMO, DNS and DHCP to the `DC-Primary` server.

I've been reading a lot and it seems lots of people have different ideas as to how to do this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer FSMO roles in any order. You don't have to migrate DNS if it's Active Directory integrated, that happens automatically. All three DCs will be DNS servers with authority over the zone.

You can configure DHCP on the new DC any time but leave the zone(s) disabled. When you're ready, deactivate the zone on the outgoing DC and activate it on the new one. Make sure if you have any DHCP relay agents on the network that they are updated with the IP address of the new DC.

Once you're done with the old DC (i.e., DHCP and all FSMO roles migrated), uninstall AD services and DNS from it, remove it from the domain, and decommission it. Then you might merely add its IP address to your new DC's interface rather than change the new DC's IP. A Windows server can have more than one IP configured on a single interface.

Comment: Excellent point in the right direction. Thank you!  Would it be ok to transfer the fsmo role during the day during production? I seem to remember it being pretty seamless.

Comment: @drpcken Yes. FSMO roles are usually only used when they are needed, which is infrequently. For example, the RID Master pretty much only does something when a new RID has to be generated. The PDC Advertiser is probably the most "busy" role. Remember, you can seize FSMO roles if the holder of any roles crashes and can't be recovered. The one thing that could get you totally caught out is that when a DC boots, it may need to contact a PDC advertiser sometimes to start AD services. If you lose your PDC advertiser for too long and reboot all DCs, you could lose the domain. Never seen that happen.

Comment: I don't plan on losing the domain ;-)   I plan on transferring roles while all domain controllers are up and running.

Comment: @drpcken You can't transfer a role to or from a DC that is not up and running. And I guess I wasn't clear that yes you can transfer all the roles in the middle of the day and no one will ever know. What you don't want to do is transfer roles at the same time another admin is installing AD services on a new DC. I doubt that's a risk for you.

Comment: Great! I just transferred all my FSMO roles about 30 minutes ago.  Replication looks good. I'm going to look into transferring dns and dhcp next.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm really nervous about migrating DNS.  It's configured on the new domain controller and I see my zones.  I should just be able to decommission the old domain controller and change the IP to match the old DC right?

Comment: Yes you can decommission the old DC without doing anything more to DNS. **Make sure you uninstall the AD services and DNS and remove it from the domain**. I **strongly** suggest you do not *change* the IP of the new DC. Instead, **add** the IP address of the old DC to the new DC, so the new DC will have two IP addresses.

Comment: Excellent.  What about my clients who's `%logonserver% is set to the domain controller I'm removing?  I've checked a few and they are all pointed to my secondary domain controller mostly.  Though my exchange server still shows the `pdc` domain controller as it's `%logonserver%`, which is the domain controller I'm about to decommission.  Is this something that will change automatically?

Comment: And also I like your idea of adding the address as a secondary IP. This way I can update DHCP to hand out the new dns address after their lease renews.

Comment: @drpcken %logonserver% is not a setting. It's a read-only environment variable set when the user logs on. You don't have to pay attention to it at all.

Comment: I may need to make another question for this, but in my DNS records, under `_msdcs` it still hows my old domain controller (and thats the only record).  I already dcpromo'd it off the domain and removed it from the domain.  Is this something that will work itself out?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, its a NS (name server) record

Comment: @drpcken If you add it as a secondary address on the new DC, it won't matter. If you didn't uninstall DNS from the old DC before you shut it down, then you may want to do a little manual DNS cleanup, which again won't matter much if you add the old DC's address to the new DC.

Comment: I did unistall dns and removed it before shutting it down.  It won't be a problem if I delete that Name Server record ?  It's the only record in the folder.  Thanks again for all your help!